# TFS build custom conditions for running a task - check if specific previous task has failed

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

TFS build allows to specify conditions for running a task: [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/process/conditions?view=vsts).

The condition I would like to define is: a specific task [addressed by name or other mean] has failed.

This is similar to `Only when a previous task has failed`, but I want to specify which previous task that is.

Looking at the examples I don't see any condition that is addressing a specific task outcome, only the entire build status.

Is it possible? any workaround to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't seem like there's an out-of-the-box solution for this requirement, but I can come up with (an ugly :)) workaround.

Suppose your specific task (the one you examine in regards to its status) is called `A`. The goal is to call another build task (let's say `B`) only in case `A` fails.

You can do the following:

- Define a [custom build variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/build/variables?view=vsts&tabs=batch#user-defined-variables), call it `task.A.status` and set to `success`
- Create another build task, e.g. `C` and schedule it right after `A`; condition it to only run if `A` fails - there's a standard condition for that
- The task `C` should only do one thing - set `task.A.status` build variable to 'failure' (like this, if we are talking PowerShell: `Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=task.A.status]failure"`)
- Finally, the task `B` is scheduled sometime after `C` and [is conditioned](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/process/conditions?view=vsts#enable-a-custom-condition) to run in case `task.A.status` equals `failure`, like this: `eq(variables['task.A.status'], 'failure')`

I might be incorrect in syntax details, but you should get the general idea. Hope it helps.