# How to run task conditionally when previous task result was successful but with errors

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration

How to run task conditionally when previous task result was successful but with errors?

I have following task structure:

- task 1
- task 2
- task 3
- more tasks

**Main goal** is to run **Task 3** if either task 1 **or** task 2 was successful. Also - to run task 2 if certain conditions were not met in task 1 (eg. there were errors).

My current settings are:

Task 1 might finish with errors, so option "Continue on error" was enabled.
I would like to run task 2 only if task 1 finishes with errors (and option "Only when a previous task has failed" does not work in this case, while "Continue on error" was enabled). In task 3 right now there is option "Only when all previous tasks have succeeded" enabled.

Maybe I should try different approach? Or maybe there is a proper "Custom conditions" for such case?

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let us know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: @Drop Have you tried below solutions provided by Leo and Fairoz? Any good news?

Comment: @LeviLu-MSFT Hello, unfortunately not yet. But for now I was able to reduce my case so all needed steps are done in script and then I had to switch to other task. But I will test those solution in some free time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to run task conditionally when previous task result was successful but with errors?

You could set following custom condition for the task 2 with Custom conditions:

```
in(variables['Agent.JobStatus'], 'Succeeded', 'SucceededWithIssues')
```

[image]

Besides, if you main goal is to run Task 3 if either task 1 or task 2 was successful, then you can also set set following custom condition for the task 3：

```
in(variables['Agent.JobStatus'], 'Succeeded', 'SucceededWithIssues')
```

BTW, the option "Only when all previous tasks have succeeded" should also meet your needs.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Agent.JobStatus holds the result of current task in execution not the previous one. Thus the expression mentioned above doesn't work. A release level variable needs to be created to be read in the custom expression. You may want to update your answer.

Comment: @Fairoz, Thanks your reply. Set `task.A.status` is a good idea, but it is limited, if the task is not powershell task, we could not to set `task.A.status`.

Comment: In my case for Task2 I had to set `in(variables['Agent.JobStatus'], 'SucceededWithIssues')` so that Task2 is skipped in case of successful Task1.

Answer (score 1):

You could refer the answer on this post  and create variables to assign status of the task.> [TFS build custom conditions for running a task - check if specific previous task has failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50351769/tfs-build-custom-conditions-for-running-a-task-check-if-specific-previous-task)

Then, use custom conditions to check the previous tasks:
in(variables['task.A.status'], 'SucceededWithIssues')

Refer more Job check functions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#job-status-functions)